# Webshop - where to pay taxes?

Tags: taxes, online-shopping

Say I would have a website that sells products and ships them worldwide. Say that I am personally located on a continent that is different from that where my supplier is based. Moreover, assume that my supplier would ship orders directly to customers worldwide. Where, and how much sales tax would I have to pay in such a case?

Comment: That will depend on the laws of each country and the treaties between the countries. No general answer, as far as I know. Heck, the US is still figuring out how to handle this between states....

Comment: @keshlam Haha, so how should I know then? There must be more online shops that have faced the same.

Comment: Nobody promised that international commerce was going to be easy ... Of course companies have solved this.